# Cannot install Elementary OS 6

Tags: elementary-project

elementaryos-6.0-daily.20210113.iso

A hardware error occurs during installation and the installation does not complete.

Redmibook-13R
R7 4700U
Vega 7
16 gb
1TB Nvme Intel Optain 660p [image]

Update: Rufus and elementaryos-6.0-daily.20210114.iso helped me

Comment: Not much info there. Maybe set bios/ efi to uefi (legacy off)?

Comment: Can you look again?

Comment: Using only uefi. Legacy didnt work

Comment: Seems installation media is not proper made. What medium is used and how is it created? (bootable usb made with rufus for example) 

Is the capture from installation in demo/ live mode? U could open terminal and tail /varlog/syslog?

Comment: cant u install straight away, without entering demo?

Comment: Same happens to me. Could you install it?